# Primary numbers, how to improve my algorithm

Tags: java

I'am Try to code algorithm to generate all prime numbers for t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

And my algorithm works fine, but he is too slow :(

How I can improve him ? In my opinon, problem is in `addPrimeNumbers` method.

```
class PrimeNumbers{

    private static int m = 0;
    private static int n = 0;
    private static int t = 0;
    private static int i = 0;
    private static String beforeSeparate;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static List<int[]> scope = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        t = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
        if (checkT(t)) {

            beforeSeparate = sc.nextLine();

            if (separate(beforeSeparate).length == 2) {
                m = separate(beforeSeparate)[0];
                n = separate(beforeSeparate)[1];
                i++;
            }
            if (checkM(m) && checkN(n) && t != 1 && n - m <= 100000) {
                int firstScope[] = {m,n};
                scope.add(firstScope);
                repeatReader();
            }
            else if (t == 1 && checkM(m) && checkN(n) && n - m <= 100000){
                int firstScope[] = {m,n};
                scope.add(firstScope);
            }
            for (int[] aScope : scope) {
                addPrimeNumbers(aScope[0], aScope[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void repeatReader(){
        beforeSeparate = sc.nextLine();
        if (separate(beforeSeparate).length == 2){
            m = separate(beforeSeparate)[0];
            n = separate(beforeSeparate)[1];
            i++;
            int nextScope[] = {m,n};
            scope.add(nextScope);
            if (i < t){
                repeatReader();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addPrimeNumbers(int i, int i1) {
        String result = "";

        for (int j = i; j <= i1 ; j++) {

            int counters = 0;
            for (int num = j; num >= i ; num--) {

                if (j % num == 0){
                    counters = counters +1;
                }
            }
            if (counters == 2){
                result = result + j + "\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static boolean checkT(int i){
        return i > 0 && i <= 10;
    }

    private static boolean checkMinMax(int i) {
        return i >= 1 && i <= 1000000000;
    }

    private static boolean checkM(int i) {
        return checkMinMax(i) && n > 0 && i <= n;
    }

    private static boolean checkN(int i) {
        return checkMinMax(i) && m > 0 && i >= m;
    }

    private static int[] separate(String i){
        String twoValue[] = i.split(" ");

        m = Integer.parseInt(twoValue[0]);
        n = Integer.parseInt(twoValue[1]);
        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(twoValue[0]), Integer.parseInt(twoValue[1])};
    }
}
```

Comment: This question belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: inteliJ free version

Comment: How much RAM your computer have?

Comment: 8GB, why are you asking?

Comment: I think that your algorithm is not slow. That's your computer, because IntelliJ IDEA is high weighted IDE..

Comment: there is a page checking the algorithm for which I want to upload this algorithm and shows that I am exceeding 6 seconds: /

Comment: first number which you input is numbers of case example: 2, and then u give a scope of numbers like "1 100"

Answer (score 0):

I've executed your program in `Command Line`. And it executed within a millisecond, So I don't think that your Algorithm is slow.

Maybe the `IDE` is slow, as you mentioned that you're using `IntelliJ IDEA`(Which is a very high-weighted `IDE`), so it can be possible that due to your computer's configurations, `IDEA` is working slow.

Problem can be anything but your code is not at all slow, its working perfectly. ;)

Happy Coding!